# Is it true that every function in JavaScript is a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5

I understand that every function in JavaScript is a first-class object and it has an internal property [[scope]] which hosts the binding records of the function's free variables. However, there are two special cases.

1. Is the function created by Function constructor also a closure? The function object created by Function constructor is special, because its [[scope]] may not refer to the lexical environments of its outer functions, but only the global context. For example,

   ```
   var a = 1; 
   var fn = (function outer() {
       var a = 2; 
       var inner = new Function('alert(a); ');
       return inner;
   })();
   fn(); // will alert 1, not 2.
   ```

   This is unintuitive. Is this also called closure?
2. If an inner function doesn't have any free variables, can we say a closure is formed when the inner function is created? For example,

   ```
   // This is a useless case only for academic study
   var fn = (function outer() {
       var localVar1 = 1,
           localVar2 = 2;
       return function() {};
   })();
   ```

   In this case, fn refers to an empty function object which was created as an inner function. It has no free variables. In this case can we say a closure is formed?

Comment: So what is your definition of "closure"?

Comment: Further comments on this behavior available here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1909-javascript-function-constructor-does-not-create-a-closure.htm The behavior seems related to `eval` behavior (indirect vs. direct call). Also see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function --- *"Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. "*

Comment: Question #2 is more of a philosophical "if a tree falls in a forest" question.

Comment: @MörreNoseshine Thanks for the links to Ben Nadel's posts and MDN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is the function created by Function constructor also a closure?

Yes, it closes over the global scope. That might be unintuitive because all other JavaScript closures close over their lexical scope, but it still matches our [definition of a closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). In your example, `a` is a free variable, and resolves to the `a` in an other scope when the `inner`/`fn` function is called somewhere.

> If an inner function doesn't have any free variables, can we still call it a closure?

Depends on whom you ask. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651614/1048572) say Yes, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/1048572) call them "uninteresting closures", personally I say No because [they don't reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8667141/1048572) an outer scope.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, wonderful explanation. In the second case, the outer() function will be garbage collected after we execute the code, since it's no longer referenced. But what's in the [[scope]] internal property of fn?  Or put it simply, does the function object fn refers to remember it was created  in outer() scope?

Comment: Well, if you follow the ES5 spec the [[scope]] of `inner` stores the lexical environment of `outer`, with its `outer` and `a` variables - so everything is still accessible and remembered. If you follow an actual ES implementation, and inspect `inner` with your debugger, you don't see any scope references - it doesn't need them, as there are no free variables.

Answer (score 5):

> Note: Functions created with the Function constructor do not create
>   closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the
>   global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access
>   their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope
>   in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from
>   using eval with code for a function expression.

from https://developer.mozilla.org