# Is that a closure?

Tags: javascript

Is the code below a closure? Why?

```js
var getContact = (function(){
 var person = {name: "John Doe"};
 return {aFriend: person};
})();
console.log(getContact.aFriend.name);
//outputs: John Doe
```

Comment: NO... This is not a closure. You are just copying that variable to an object's property's value.

Comment: It **has** a closure. The code below can't be a closure, the code below might have a variable as a closure, but the code itself isn't the closure. Problem of grammar.

Comment: [is-it-true-that-every-function-in-javascript-is-a-closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252621/is-it-true-that-every-function-in-javascript-is-a-closure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

There is no function declared inside another function that is accessible after the outer function has finished executing.

In this example:

```
function createClosure() {
    var foo = 0;
    function bar() {
        alert(foo);
    }
    return bar;
}

var myFunc = createClosure();
```

… the variable `foo` is closed over so there is a closure.

Comment: Is this a closure?:
`var getContact = (function(){
 var person = {name: "John Doe"};
    var message= "Hi message";
  function hi(){alert(message);}
 return {aFriend: person, sayHi:hi};
})();
console.log(getContact.sayHi());`

Comment: @Legends: The `hi` function is a closure that persists as long as `getContact` keeps a reference to the object and the object keeps a reference to it via the `sayHi` property, yes.

Answer (score 2):

All JavaScript functions are closures; they keep a reference to the [lexical environment object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) that's active when they're created. So technically there is *briefly* a closure created there, but in that code no closure endures for any length of time. The function is created, called, and then released; nothing maintains a reference to it, so it doesn't live on, and the lexical environment object it referenced can be reclaimed. Creating an *object* in a function does not give the object a reference to the function (or the environment object), so the function isn't retained, and so it doesn't retain its enclosing environment in memory.

Contrast with:

```js
(function outer(x) {
    setTimeout(function inner() {
        alert(x);
    }, 100);
})("foo");
```

There, we create two closures (`outer` and `inner`) but `outer` is released almost immediately (like your example); `inner` is released 100ms or so later after the timer fires and the timer subsystem releases its reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

getContact is a IIFE ( immediately-invoked function expression) which returns an object. Here no inner function is created which refers to the outer function's environment variable. It should not be considered closure in my opinion, still waiting for explanation which can justify this as a closure.

Comment: What I understood is, that technically every function is a closure, but if you don't return an "inner function" the closure is not persisted after the function execution ends. A function has a private scope == "closure"?!
Actually I think, "closure" == "persisted private scope of a function", that is what is commonly understood as closure. I hope I could explain it well.