# Returned object from a function count as a reference to the closure for the javascript garbage collector?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about closures and I want to know a bit about the garbage collector behavior. In the following code:

```
function valueMaker(name, value) {
    var final = {};
    final[name] = value;
    final[double] = value*2;
    return final;
}
first = valueMaker('first', 1);
```

When I call `valueMaker` it creates a closure where I have the `final` object, then, it returns the object.

My question is: The returned object count as a reference to the closure? or JavaScript is smart enough to know when I want to keep the closure alive?

Comment: I don't see a closure, here.

Comment: @NineBerry: When you execute a function, there is always a closure associate to the function execution: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: No, closures are bound to the creation of functions, not the execution of functions. When a function is created, it can bind to the local variables of an outer function wherein the inner function is created. This is then called a closure. We don't see this here, because valueMaker does not access any outside variables and there is no other function created inside valueMaker.

Comment: @NineBerry I would be awesome if you provide a reference to prove that. Everything I find makes me think you're wrong. 

From mozilla developers: "A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time that the closure was created." [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures]

closure = function + lexical environment.

Comment: The Mozilla doc says the same as I did. You just have to look at the examples. There is no case of a closure in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I call `valueMaker` it creates a closure

No. There is no function inside `valueMaker`, so there's no closure anywhere.

A closure was created when the `function valueMaker` definition itself was evaluated, and that closure will be *used* when you call `valueMaker()`. Though it's not even an [interesting closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252701/1048572), given that there are no free variables that it would use.

Comment: "personally I say No because they don't reference an outer scope.". 
I will never understand that urge to put the personal opinion behind what the truly happens (in this case, the compiler does).

Comment: @lcjury However, the spec says something different. I wanted to emphasize that it depends on the view, there are arguments both for and against calling a function without free variables a closure - in any case, those cases aren't interesting. To be honest, I didn't remember that I said No two years ago, and here I'm making the opposite point.

Comment: Completely agree with you, but I wanted to know the compiler point of view. Not the programmer point of view.

I'm a little tired of this, each month I have a "strange" question, and when I ask other programmers about it all I got is "why do you want to know that?, anybody cares... better use this and ignore that...".